# How to make the text cursor in a text field start a few px in?

Tags: javascript, css, resize, textfield, text-cursor

I am wanting a text field that has a cursor that starts a few px (say maybe 4) in from the left-hand side. I know it can be done if you make the text field to size using padding, but I wanted to know if there is any way possible without using padding to resize the text box, but using the height and width CSS.

An ideas or input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by height and width?

Comment: I am setting the field with the following:

`
.input {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 10px;
  }
`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use the [`text-indent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/text-indent) property:

```
input {
  text-indent:20px;
}
```

You can also use padding with a fixed width. This will keep the width fixed at `100px` but still do your padding.

```
input {
  padding-left: 10px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work in Internet Explorer. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Alright. That works good. What about a way to specify the text size?

Comment: Internet Explorer does weird things with everything. It really should be taken off the market.

Comment: [`font-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/font-size). I recommend [reading](http://www.tizag.com/cssT/) [more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Getting_Started) about [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/default.asp)